# Is XSS still a risk if your site does not allows users to log in?

Tags: security, xss

We're about to launch a public facing site, and the security review team has come back with a XSS vulnerability. It's essentially a brochure site - there are no logins, and no user submitted information is publicly displayed.

Is XSS still something we should be concerned about?

Comment: If users cannot submit any data then XSS is impossible.

Comment: What about non-persistent attacks? ie crafting a url to the vulnerable page on the site and enticing another user to visit that url with the intent of stealing their information?

Comment: @Kirk Woll, If the security team has come back with a working exploit, then they it is probably possible on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**,  XSS allows hackers to control the content on your site and normally takes a single function call to fix.  It takes less effort to fix this issue, than for you to post this question to SO about it.

Lets say you are Fox News,  someone could use XSS to fabricate the news.   Further more it could be used to deliver a drive by download attack to your users.  In your case someone could create a fake brochure with outrageous claims.

Comment: Could you explain how this would be done with a non-persistent vector?

Comment: @ScottE, by using short-url services to hide the XSS vector and (mass) mail the url. Alternatively, you can do the same by loading the fox-page inside an iframe of 100%

Comment: Short url services actually allow someone to use script tags (or their equivalent)??

Comment: @Henri thank you,  you are correct. and @ScottE short url services normally don't care what the URL is,  except for maybe mcaf.ee.  Also don't forget about digg/reddit/slashdot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, XSS vulnerabilities need not be focused at user data.  They can be used to turn your site into a malware distribution site.  Imagine, an attacker puts in an XSS that pops up an alert saying "Your computer may have a virus", and starts a download for some scammer's fake virus scanner.  You will be blamed by any users who fall for the scam.